# Tags XML sendo geradas com prefixos

Tags: delphi, xml

Estou criando um arquivo XML pelo Delphi e se eu uso o prefixo na criação da primeira tag, o prefixo "ns1" é adicionado a todas as tags que virão abaixo, gerando erro na integração com o WebService.
O que eu preciso é que a primeira tag seja gerada com o prefixo e as outras não.

Quando utilizo esse comando na criação da primeira tag, o prefixo é repetido em todas as outras:

```
xDOC := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
xDOC.Active := True;
xDOC.Encoding := 'UTF-8';

xNOD := xDOC.AddChild('ns1:ReqEnvioLoteRPS'); // Essa linha...
if not(xNOD.NodeName = 'ReqEnvioLoteRPS') then
  xNOD := xDOC.ChildNodes.FindNode('ReqEnvioLoteRPS');

xNOD := xNOD.AddChild('Cabecalho');
```

Nesse caso, a tag "Cabeçalho" é gerada assim: `"ns1:Cabecalho"`, dando erro na integração, pois é pedido que o cabeçalho seja assim: `"Cabecalho"`.
Se eu gero a linha sem o prefixo:

```
xNOD := xDOC.AddChild('ReqEnvioLoteRPS'); // Essa linha...
```

Dá erro, porque a integração pede esse "ns1" na primeira tag.

Eu preciso que o "ns1" seja informado apenas na tag principal do XML "ReqEnvioLoteRPS", e não nas demais...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa `AddChild()` para adicionar uma nova tag filho e não especifica explicitamente um namespace, a tag filho herda o namespace da tag pai.

Isso é um comportamento do próprio `AddChild()`, você não pode alterá-lo. É por isso que o prefixo ns1: é herdado em todos os nós filhos.

Para resolver isso você pode fazer uma sobrecarga do método `AddChild()`

Veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48172801/delphi-berlin-10-1-ixmldocument-root-node-prefix/48173365#48173365), é exatamente a solução do seu problema.

Comment: Certo. Estarei fazendo os testes aqui, e assim que eu conseguir fazer a integração voltarei e marcarei a sua resposta como resolvida. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Resolvido! Muito obrigado pela ajuda @LGregianin

Comment: Que bom que resolveu.